# How to convert this code with switch expression and comparison operations

Tags: c#, .net

I implemented the code using if...else.. This is working properly.

```
public static byte GetLengthWithCascadedIfElse(int number)
        {
            if (number < 10 && number > -10)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (number > 10 && number < 100)
            {
                return 2;
            }
            if (number > 1000000 && number < int.MaxValue)
            {
                return 3;
            }
            if (number < -100000000 && number > -1000000000)
            {
                return 4;
            }

            return 10;
        }
```

My problem is that I need to implement the code above, using switch expression. I tried! Its dont work.

```
        public static byte GetLengthWithSwitchExpression(int number)
        {
            return number switch
            {
                _ when number == 0 && number == -1 => 1,
                _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
            };
        }
```

CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: This isn't even remotely the right syntax for a switch statement, let alone `c#` in general.. Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)?

Comment: @tnw It's a `C# 8` feature called switch expressions - [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions). Your link is about the switch statement.

Comment: Notice that the value of `number` can't be both `0` and `1` at the same time; what is being checked in `_ when number == 0 && number == -1`.

Comment: @pfx My mistake! Thank you

Comment: First, I think you want to use the OR relational operator rather than AND - number cannot be equal to 0 and -1.  Per the error, I think maybe you need to explicitly cast the return value to a (byte).

Comment: The function in OP, copy/pasted into a test project, compiles and runs just fine for me. I don't see any reason for the compile error you list. Are you sure OP contains the exact code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're thinking of C# 9's relational patterns?

```
number switch
{
    > -10 and < 10 => 1,
    > 10 and < 100 => 2,
    > 1000000 and < int.MaxValue => 3, 
    > -1000000000 and < -100000000 => 4,
    _ => 10
};
```

Or C# 8's `when`?

```
number switch
{
    int a when a > -10 && a < 10 => 1,
    int a when a > 10 && a < 100 => 2,
    int a when a > 1000000 && a < int.MaxValue => 3, 
    int a when a > -1000000000 && a < -100000000 => 4,
    _ => 10
};
```

Your stab at the conversion seems to use totally different parameters to what you say want/works.. so I didn't try to convert "the case of 0 and 1"

I did wonder if your "less than int.maxvalue" is redundant? Or will you really have a maxvalue passed in, and want it to be 10?

Comment: Thanks! I i use c# 8. I didn’t know to add an extra variable 'a' (as in the example). And i fix int.maxvalue

Comment: Relational patterns aren't preview. C#9 has been out for over a month

Comment: @Maxim As I understand it, it's normally used for "Type matching that provides a variable of that type to then further inspect properties of", so it's like `switch Shape (case) Triangle t when t.Hypotenuse > 2` - a bit like `if(someX is Triangle t && t.Hypotenuse > 2` ... That whole "check it's the type and return a variable of that type" thing that we do when we want to write code that craps all over what polymorphism was hoping to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert if statement to switch statement or switch expression from visualstudio

This refactoring applies to:

C#
What: Convert an if statement to a switch statement or to the C# 8.0 switch expression.

When: You want to convert an if statement to a switch statement or a switch expression and vice versa.

Why: If you are using an if statement, this refactoring enables an easy transition to switch statements or switch expressions.

How-to

1-Place your cursor in the if keyword.

2-Press Ctrl+. to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu.

3-Select from the following two options:

Select Convert to 'switch' statement.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMsQ2.png)

Select Convert to 'switch' expression.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdCoZ.png)

Comment: Thank you. I’ve used this tool in other ways. It’s in this method that it didn’t help me